# How to loop over two lists at the same time and sort it in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach

I have two lists which is already sorted based on a date. These two lists are of different types.
But both these lists contain a date type property.

For eg: List A consists of employees and List B consists of Department

For Eg:

```
Sample List A:
  {
    { 
      id=1;
      Date=12/7/2016;
      some other data..
    },
    { 
      id=2;
      Date=13/5/2016;
      some other data..
    },
   }



 Sample List B:

  {
    { 
      id=1;
      Date=1/9/2016;
      some other data..
    },
    { 
      id=2;
      Date=19/6/2016;
      some other data..
    },
   }
```

I need to loop through these two lists simultaneously to get the results sorted based on the date property.

So if the highest date value is from list B then call a function to print details of that record from list B. Next find the next highest date value from both list, and now if it is from list A then call a function to print details of that record from list A.

Comment: what have you try already?

Comment: SO is not a ready-made code service,please show us your try

Comment: I think this is exact [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996188/how-to-combine-two-types-of-c-sharp-lists-into-one) you asked yesterday and got answer

Comment: If you think your existing question was poorly worded or needed better examples, you should **edit** it, not post a new question with updated details.

Comment: if it is a duplicate then stackoverflow should mark both questions as duplicates not just one, so people reading any dup would know it is a dup  and not waste time answering either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is vague one, probably you're looking for `Concat`:
Let `BaseAB` be a *base class*, shared *interface* etc. which contains
at least `Date` property

```
   List<ClassA> A = ...
   List<ClassB> B = ...

   var result A
     .Concat<BaseAB>(B)
     .OrderByDescending(item => item.Date);

   foreach (var item in result) {
     var itemA = item as A;

     if (itemA != null) {
       ... 
     }
     else {
       var itemB = item as B;  
       ...  
     } 
   }
```

In (ugly) case `A` and `B` have *nothing* in common, you can use an artificial `Tuple<DateTime, Object>` representation:

```
var result = ListA
   .Select(item => new Tuple<DateTime, Object>(item.Date, item))
   .Concat(ListB
      .Select(item => new Tuple<DateTime, Object>(item.Date, item)))
   .OrderByDescending(tuple => tuple.Item1)
   .Select(tuple => tuple.Item2);
```

Comment: Thanks. What is this Object in Tuple<DateTime, Object> ? Also how can I loop through this result?

Comment: @Shafeek: object in the `Tuple<DateTime, Object>`, (`tuple.Item2` to be exact) is the item of either `ListA` or `ListB` (`Object` since `A` and `B` have *nothing* in common); so you have result as `IEnumerable<Object>` and can use the same `foreach` as in the case above

Comment: Thank you very much